# know MPMusicPlayerController song playing finished

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am implementing one iOS app which is playing songs in the foreground and background using the `MPMusicPlayerController`. When I am in the foreground I am able to go to the next song using the below code.

```
long currentPlaybackTime = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
//NSLog(@"%lu",currentPlaybackTime);
int currentHours = (currentPlaybackTime / 3600);
int currentMinutes = ((currentPlaybackTime / 60) - currentHours*60);
int currentSeconds = (currentPlaybackTime % 60);

// The total duration of the track...
long totalPlaybackTime = ([[[musicPlayer nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty: @"playbackDuration"] longValue])-currentPlaybackTime;
int tHours = (totalPlaybackTime / 3600);
int tMins = ((totalPlaybackTime/60) - tHours*60);
int tSecs = (totalPlaybackTime % 60);

float a = currentPlaybackTime;
float b = [[[musicPlayer nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty: @"playbackDuration"] floatValue];

float fltTime= a / b;
self.positionSlider2.value = fltTime;

if(tHours == 0 && tMins == 0 && tSecs == 0)
{
    [self nextSong:nil];
}
```

but I can't go to the next song when I am in the background why because timers are not working in background. And I have tried to use the

1. `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`, but this is also only working in foreground. Could anyone tell me how to go to next song when the app is in the background. Please let me know if I am not clear.
2. Tried to use the

`[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime" options:0 context:nil]` but this is not working in foreground and background.

Any ideas/suggestions could be very helpful.